# Application is crashing in Debug dll MSVCR100D.dll when running from standard user

Tags: c++, windows

A brief story about my problem:

My application [which is compiled in VC++ 2010] is supposed to have fewer viewing/working rights to Standard user, while of-course in Administrative user it will have full permission.
Few days back when I tried to run the application [installed version that is release binaries] in Standard user I saw a crash in ***MFC140ud.dll*** [weird]. It should not be *ud* version. Anyways, in my programs & features [I am a Win7 user] I saw Runtime & redistributable of VS2015.I uninstalled them.

I restarted my computer with not much luck- and I was still getting crash but in different dlls.

It shows two dialog boxes showing errors. One is showing error in MSVCR100d.dll and second is showing in ntdll.dll

Here is the problem signature from the two boxes:

**Problem signature:**

Problem Event Name: APPCRASH 
Application Name:   MyAppName.exe
Application Version:    4.5.64.0
Application Timestamp:  594a41e2
Fault Module Name:  MSVCR100D.dll
Fault Module Version:   10.0.40219.325
Fault Module Timestamp: 4df2be37
Exception Code: 80000003
Exception Offset:   0011b545
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

--

**Problem signature:**
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: MyAppName.exe
  Application Version:  4.5.64.0
  Application Timestamp:    594a41e2
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.23796
  Fault Module Timestamp:   59028e17
  Exception Code:   c015000f
  Exception Offset: 00083af6
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 55c7
  Additional Information 2: 55c739abdb4e531959bbe02ef6e9e097
  Additional Information 3: e422
  Additional Information 4: e422b1470321edbfed7e5b3f5a1b3d28

--
I reinstalled VS2010 redistributable but no luck.

I see same error even if I try it running as admin [right click and select Run as admin].

If I run it from Administrator account it works fine.

Also, I want to add- if it helps anybody to help me correct- usually I keep windows updates, but, few days back it installed a long list of updates.
So I think it is Win7 updates causing problem but not sure.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: MFC140ud.dll is the debug MFC dll and should not be distributed and is not in the redist pack).  Run dependency walker and find out why it is being used.

Comment: Richard Critten! Thanks, but let me confirm you that it is not showing any dependency on any of debug dlls. And that is why it is weird situation for me. Also, the point to think is - if I run it from [Win7] Administrator account then it runs fine. But crashing when running from Standard user. If it would be dependent on any debug dll then it should show same behaviour everywhere without differentiating the type of user.

Comment: I am still waiting for some help. I am also walking around [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/746aafe6-9350-48f9-8c27-ffb19df4a86f/getting-debug-assertion-in-mfc100uddll-in-release-mode?forum=vcgeneral) but still no clue.